# return parameters of best score of cross validation for linear regression in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation

this is the code for cross validation for the linear regression model. as you can see the best score is 0.7 but how can I retrieve the parameters (coefficients) of the model with the best score??

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
scores = cross_val_score(clf, data_f[features], data_f['temperature'], cv=5)
scores
```

this is the result

```
array([ 0.61858698,  0.52880606,  0.70729139,  0.48306915,  0.68386676])
```

Comment: You should look at the documentation for GridSearchCV to get a simple answer to this question or use KFold and manually track the results. cros_val_score doesn't return what you want.

Comment: Actually I tried first both of the ways GridSearchCV and KFold(manually tracking results) but I had some issues so I thought there is someway to find the coefficients using cross_val_score()

Comment: Any way I get back to the KFold and it worked. Thank you